# Merge case-related tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

There are two each for lowercase and uppercase tags, and they are split in popularity.  The hyphenated version being more popular for one and the non-hyphenated for the other:

[uppercase] × 13
[upper-case] × 36
[lowercase] × 30
[lower-case] × 19

<s>The preferred tags should be [lowercase] and [uppercase], those being words often spelled without hyphens.</s>

Because you can only suggest to synonym the less popular to the more popular tag, there are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/upper-case/synonyms) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lowercase/synonyms) that would enforce inconsistent use if both got applied.

#### Update

As someone studiously manually retagged all [uppercase] into [upper-case] (the *opposite* of what I proposed here, and only an hour after I posted this question, so I'd really be interested in your thoughts), it got me thinking: several questions are tagged [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upper-case+lower-case) and every time either tag is appropriate it seems a single tag that represents both could be used instead.  What could that tag be?  [[case-sensitive]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitive) seems appropriate and popular—moreso than all upper-/lowercase combined (just barely).

Even [case-insensitive] could be synonymed to [case-sensitive], since any insensitive question deals with case sensitivity issues.  [case-sensitivity] might even be better than [case-sensitive], but it doesn't exist yet.

What is the single tag we can use to tag all of these similar questions?  I vote for all the tags mentioned here to be merged into [[case-sensitivity]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitivity).  With one synonym voted-in already ([lower-case] to [lowercase]) and the multiple tag merges required, this needs a diamond's special touch in any ... *case.*

Comment: Perhaps we could retag them all as `[majuscule]` and `[miniscule]`.

Comment: If SO was a typography site, I'd prefer that. :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that [uppercase] and [lowercase] are the desired forms here; done.